# AWS Lambda not receiving static IP in spite of routing through NAT gateway with EIP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nat, static-ip-address

AWS Lambda configured to go through NAT gateway with an EIP is not receiving the IP and keeps getting a random one.

I've created a Lambda sitting on a Subnet (private) which redirects all traffic into another Subnet (public) which has a NAT Gateway on it with an attached EIP. 
The public Subnet redirects all its traffic to an IGW attached to this same VPC.
All the Lambda does is shoot off an http request and receive a response.

I've checked whether traffic is going through the IGW and NAT, and it looks like it does, because when I remove either one from the respective Route Tables, the Lambda times out on the execution.
I can also see in the NAT's monitoring tab, that when I run the Lambda, there's activity..

Sending this as the options of a nodejs http request Lambda:

```
{
  "options": {
    "hostname": "www.whatsmyip.org",
    "method": "GET",
    "port": 443
  }
}
```

When I'm trying to 'prod' www.whatsmyip.com to see the IP address of the Lambda, I keep getting different random results, instead of receiving back the EIP attached to the NAT Gateway.

Here's a layout of the setup:
[image: CF Layout]

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: yes and no
i've tried using other "whatsmyip" types of websites, and they did show the correct address.. so i just left it at that, instead of trying to figure out what was different about "www.whatsmyip.org" specifically

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an IGW when you don't accept incoming connections from the Internet? Your setting seems okay. Remove the NAT GW routing to IGW, remove IGW (not needed). Should work.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something.
Don't I need the IGW to go outside just as well?

Also, I've already tried removing the routing from the NAT to the IGW (without removing the IGW itself though), and the Lambda timed out.

Comment: @Poster You are correct, you need to Internet Gateway to give public subnets access to the internet and your NAT Gateway is running in that public subnet.